# How do I select block level elements and their parents containing only a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the plugin that i wrote and it seems to accomplish a large percentage of what I intended add click handlers to parent div, li, and other block elements containing just a link. i need to limit the selection of the parent to only block elements, and enlarge the resulting selection if the parents are only container for  this link.

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.buttonize = function (){
    var $is_singleparent = $(this).parent().find('a:only-child').parent();
    if ($is_singleparent.length){
        $is_singleparent.css({'cursor':'pointer', border:'thin yellow solid').on('click', function () {
            window.location = $('a', this).attr('href');
        });
    }
}
})(jQuery);
// to use
$('a').buttonize();
```

The yellow border is just for debugging...
Here it is in action:
http://jsbin.com/cawijoputa/7/edit?html,css,js,output
When you look at this a few things are wrong from my intention:

- The div
  with id=d should be highlighted instead the parent div of Devaki
- The span with (inline:block) containing Lakshmi should be highlighted
  but not those inline spans containing Krsna and Maya.
- The div containing the span should be highlighted instead the span with Jagganath
- The div
  with id=n should be highlighted instead the paragraph with Narayana

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: If you follow along the bulleted list / looking at the jsbin, it should start making sense. THX

Comment: I added this: To clarify i need to limit the selection of the parent to only block elements, and enlarge the resulting selection if the parents are only container for this link.
thx for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding another `parent` method in the chain gets you mostly there. It all seems very fragile, though.

```
var $is_singleparent = $(this).parent().find('a:only-child').parent().parent();
```

Comment: yea but if that parent has other content than just the 2 children this idea fails, in my jsbin that selects the parent of it all the body...we wouldn't want to attach a click handler to that.

Comment: Right. That's the fragility I mentioned. You'll  have to anticipate quite a few possible scenarios if you aren't going to make it opt-in by using a class on the links.

Comment: yea i think for this part i need a second var like var $is_singlegrandparent = $is_singleparent.parent().find($is_singleparent).fiilter(':only-child').parent(); but i don't think you can use a jquery object find statement....

Comment: You can indeed search within jQuery objects. In fact, that's what you're always doing.

Comment: from these comments, I feel that using more indicators(classes or ids or other selectors) will simplify jQuery code, which at the end will help maintaining your code.